# Atmosphere with Android

Tags: java, jquery, android, atmosphere

First, I plan to use [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) on the server side and on the client side an Android app with a WebView in which I'll use jQuery.

But, later on a more "standard" Android application is planned (no WebViews), and I want to know whether Atmosphere can be used too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery.atmosphere.js works fine on Android. So you should be OK.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for confirming my assumptions regarding the jQuery plugin :) And regarding the latter question, can I use Atmosphere when making requests via HttpClient for example (the scenario when making an Android application which doesn't use a WebView)? Or I should search for a more specific client library for doing this?

Comment: Atmosphere will works, but you can also take a look at the AHC (AsyncHttpClient) library. That's one is used a lot with Atmosphere.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach:

**Server side:**

[Atmosphere Meteor Servlet](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Meteor,-WebSocket-and-Long-Polling)

- Meteor Servlet implementation is easy than Atmosphere runtime approach.

**Android Client side:**

[Wasync](https://github.com/Atmosphere/wasync) libraries

- Wasync libraries are used to extend the functionalities of Atmosphere framework.
- You can download sample chat application for android app from its samples.