# Which WebSocket library to use in Android app?

Tags: android, node.js, websocket

I want to add a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) to my Android app which runs in the background holding a [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) connection (possibly over several hours or even days) and regularly sends some data to a server.

Now there seems to be a bunch of WebSocket libraries for Java, and I'm not sure which one I should use:

- **[TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket)**
  Description from GitHub: A barebones WebSocket client and server implementation written in 100% Java. http://java-websocket.org/
  -- This one is linked in [my first result of googling "android websocket"](http://www.elabs.se/blog/66-using-websockets-in-native-ios-and-android-apps). However, it has quite a few open issues, especially about SSL connections, and it doesn't seem to be actively maintained at the moment.
- **[koush/AndroidAsync](https://github.com/koush/AndroidAsync)**
  Description from GitHub: Asynchronous socket, http (client+server), websocket, and socket.io library for android. Based on nio, not threads.
  -- Again many open issues, but seems to be activiley maintained/worked on.
- **[Project Tyrus](https://tyrus.java.net/)**
  Description from Website: JSR 356: Java API for WebSocket - Reference Implementation
  -- This is made by Oracle. Not sure if it works in Android.
- **[Jetty WebSocket Client API](http://Jetty%20WebSocket%20Client%20API)**
  Info from Website: Jetty also provides a Jetty WebSocket Client Library to write make talking to WebSocket servers easier.
  -- Again: Not sure if it works in Android.
- **[codebutler/android-websockets](https://github.com/codebutler/android-websockets)**
  Description from GitHub: Bare minimum websockets (hybi13/RFC) client for Android
  -- This one is used in [schwiz/android-websocket-example](https://github.com/schwiz/android-websocket-example), which is the accepted answer for the StackOverflow-question "[How to make the Android device hold a TCP connection to Internet without wake lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534732/how-to-make-the-android-device-hold-a-tcp-connection-to-internet-without-wake-lo)".
- **[Atmosphere/wasync](https://github.com/Atmosphere/wasync)**
  Description from GitHub:  WebSockets with fallback transports client library for Node.js, Android and Java http://async-io.org
- **[TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client)**
  Description from GitHub: High-quality WebSocket client implementation in Java.
- **[square/okhttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp)**
  Description from GitHub: An HTTP+SPDY client for Android and Java applications. http://square.github.io/okhttp/
  -- <s>It has a [Websocket module](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-ws).</s> As [mentioned by scorpiodawg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547517/which-websocket-library-to-use-in-android-app#comment73941371_30547517), OkHttp has built-in websocket support since version 3.5.
- **[firebase/TubeSock](https://github.com/firebase/TubeSock)**
  Description from GitHub: A WebSocket client library implemented in Java
- **[Autobahn|Android](http://autobahn.ws/android/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/crossbario/autobahn-android))**
  Description from Website: Autobahn|Android is an open-source networking library for Java/Android created by the Autobahn project that implements the WebSocket Protocol and the Web Application Messaging Protocol (WAMP) for creating native mobile WebSocket/WAMP clients. -- [cloudsurfin pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547517/which-websocket-library-to-use-in-android-app#comment58475155_30547517) that this has no support for wss.

In addition, there is a native [socket.io](http://socket.io/) client library for Android:

- **[nkzawa/socket.io-client.java](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java)**
  Description from GitHub: Full-featured Socket.IO Client Library for Java, which is compatible with Socket.IO v1.0 and later.

To use the socket.io Android client would be handy for me, because I plan to use nodejs/socket.io for the web frontend anyway. But the native client is quite young and has several open issues. And in addition to that, it is my understanding that an android app does not have any benefit of using the socket.io client library (apart from being compatible with socket.io 1.0 server), because WebSocket support can be assured at the client side.

My requirements are as follows:

- Compatibility with Android API 9 and higher
- Possibility to connect via SSL
- Keep the connection for a long time without having to hold a permanent wakelock
- Compatibility with an available nodejs websocket server implementation or with socket.io

Any suggestions which one is the right library for these requirements?

Comment: Perhaps [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere). See [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9313199/642706).

Comment: Well, maybe their android client Atmosphere/wasync. I updated my question. Any reason to choose this one? :)

Comment: I'm no expert on WebSocket nor Atmosphere. I only know that Atmosphere  is well-worn, used in many projects for [Push](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) features including WebSocket support. My only experience is indirect, in building [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) web apps. Vaadin uses Atmosphere for its automatic Push capability. But beware, WebSocket is still relatively new with many changes to its definition, specs, and various implementations during its brief history. So expect "issues" no matter how you go.

Comment: websocket from firebase https://github.com/firebase/TubeSock

Comment: FYI, Autobahn is out there and they have a flashy website.  But no notice that "secure WebSockets not implemented" until you spend the time to install and try to run it. Next.

Comment: I tried both TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket and koush/AndroidAsync. As you mentioned the former doesn;t handle SSL handskaes well so if you are using a secure connection probably better to use koush/AndroidAsync. AndroidAsyn worked perfectly out of the box. I did like better Java-WebSockets callbacks as they were cleaner.

Comment: OkHttp now supports websockets too: https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/web-sockets-now-shipping-in-okhttp-3-5-463a9eec82d1

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment so I am writing it as answer as I have gone through the same requirements you mentioned in your question and okhttp helped me to satisfy all the requirements.
It supports web sockets since the introduction of version 3.5, So its an added advantage to use okHttp(web service calls + web sockets support).
Here is the link to start with. <https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-use-websockets-on-android-with-okhttp-ba5f00aea988>

Comment: Questions like this should not be closed.

Answer (score 137):

Some notes.

- **koush/AndroidAsync** does not perform the [closing handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7) which is required by [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30357258/1174054) for details.
- **Project Tyrus** works on Android, but make sure that its license ([CDDL 1.1 and GPL 2 with CPE](https://glassfish.java.net/public/CDDL+GPL_1_1.html)) and its size ([Reducing WebSocket client jar size with ProGuard](https://blogs.oracle.com/PavelBucek/entry/reducing_websocket_client_jar_size)) meet your requirements. Also note that Tyrus may throw an exception when a text size is large (it's probably a bug). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32218168/1174054) for details.
- **Jetty**: A 2-year-ago [email thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg03281.html) in jetty-users mailing list says *"We currently have no Android compatible Jetty 9 WebSocket client. There are plans to attempt to backport the Jetty WebSocket Client from JDK 7 to JDK 5/6 for android use, but its a lower priority than finishing our implementation of JSR-356 Java WebSocket API (javax.websocket)."* Jetty's current [document](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html) about its WebSocket Client API does not mention anything about Android.
- **codebutler/android-websocket** does not perform the [closing handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7) which is required by [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) and may throw an exception on close. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185251/1174054).
- **Atmosphere/wasync** uses **AsyncHttpClient/[async-http-client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client)** as its WebSocket implementation. So, rather, AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client should be mentioned instead.
- **firebase/TubeSock** does not verify `Sec-WebSocket-Accept`. This is a violation against [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455). Also, TubeSock has a bug in building a text message. You will encounter the bug sooner or later if you use multi-byte UTF-8 characters for text messages. See [Issue 3](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-DDP/issues/3) in [delight-im/Android-DDP](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-DDP) for a long list about TubeSock problems.

## Consideration Points

Consideration points in selecting a WebSocket client implementation written in Java:

1. **Compliance**. Not a small number of implementations do not implement the [closing handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-7) required by [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455). (What happens if the closing handshake is not implemented? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34368764/1174054).)
2. **Required Java version**. Java SE 5, 6, 7, 8 or Java EE? Works even on Android?
3. **Size**. Some implementations have many dependencies.
4. **wss** support.
5. **HTTP proxy** support.
6. **wss over HTTP proxy** support. See Figure 2 in [How HTML5 Web Sockets Interact With Proxy Servers](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Web-Sockets-Proxy-Servers) about what a WebSocket client library has to do to support wss over HTTP proxy.
7. **Flexibility on SSL configuration**. `SSLSocketFactory` and `SSLContext` should be able to be utilized without unnecessary restrictions.
8. **Custom HTTP headers in the [opening handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4)**, including Basic Authentication.
9. **Custom HTTP headers in HTTP proxy negotiation**, including authentication at the proxy server.
10. **Capable of sending all the frame types** (continuation, binary, text, close, ping and pong) or not. Most implementations do not provide developers with means to send [fragmented frames](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.4) and *unsolicited* [pong frames](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.5.3) manually.
11. **Listener interface** to receive various WebSocket events. A poor interface makes developers frustrated. A rich interface helps developers write robust applications.
12. **Able to inquire WebSocket state** or not. [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) defines CONNECTING, OPEN, CLOSING and CLOSED states, but few implementations maintain their internal state transition in the defined way.
13. **Able to set a timeout value for socket connection**. (Equivalent to the second argument of `Socket.connect(SocketAddress endpoint, int timeout)` method)
14. **Able to access the underlying raw socket**.
15. **Intuitive easy-to-use API** or not.
16. **Well-documented** or not.
17. **[RFC 7692](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7692) (Compression Extensions for WebSocket)** support (aka permessage-deflate).
18. **Redirection** (3xx) support.
19. **Digest Authentication** support.

**[nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client)** covers all the above except the last two. In addition, one of its small but convenient features is to send ping/pong frames periodically. It can be achieved just by calling `setPingInterval`/`setPongInterval` methods (See [JavaDoc](http://takahikokawasaki.github.io/nv-websocket-client/)).

Disclaimer: Takahiko Kawasaki is the author of nv-websocket-client.

Comment: is nv-websocket-client library still under development ?
I faced automatic disconnection issue with TooTallNate/Java-WebSockets with error 1006 and NO reason.. does this nv-websocket also resolve it ?

Comment: nv-websocket-client is stable. To prevent automatic disconnection, you should send ping (or pong) frames periodically. To do it by TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket, you have to implement a periodical task (using Timer, Thread, ExecutorService, etc.) that constructs a `Framedata` instance representing a ping (or pong) frame and sends it by `WebSocket.sendFrame(Framedata)`. If you use nv-websocket-client, it can be achived by just calling [WebSocket.setPingInterval(int)](http://takahikokawasaki.github.io/nv-websocket-client/com/neovisionaries/ws/client/WebSocket.html#setPingInterval-long-).

Comment: As for 1006, the specification (RFC 6455) states that the code _MUST NOT be set as a status code in a Close control frame by an endpoint_. This means that the code was generated on the client side. You can get more information about disconnection through `onDisconnected` method and `onError` method of [WebSocketListener](http://takahikokawasaki.github.io/nv-websocket-client/com/neovisionaries/ws/client/WebSocketListener.html). `onError` method gives you a `WebSocketException` instance. Call its `getError()` method to see what is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am sending periodic (20 sec) text messages to server.. and receiving response from server as well (after every 120 sec)
As far as this error is concerned, the callback is coming in onClose method without any defined error...I hope sending text messages are no different than ping/pong ?
Anyways, I will try your library as well. Thanks

Comment: For wss, I tried okhttp and autobahn (also suspect of the self promotion in this answer). Autobahn was easy, but has no SSL. OkHttp has little to zero (consolidated) documentation (Feb 2016). I wasted a lot of time reading their code and their exceptions because I wasn't privy to workarounds (like set the timeout to 0, or close the incoming message) to get a bare bones example working. Dumping those two (and my frustration), I found nv (refreshingly) well documented; it worked without a fuss.

Comment: cannot thank you enough.  This should be the go-to java websocket implementation. No android ssl trickery and permessage-deflate is critical.

Comment: it's said on the `async-http-client` readme that it *currently requires JDK8*. That pretty much excludes Android, right?

Comment: Any thoughts on Square/okhttp's new websockets support? https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/web-sockets-now-shipping-in-okhttp-3-5-463a9eec82d1

Comment: @TakahikoKawasaki I'd like to reiterate scorpiodawg's question -- both NV and OkHttp have changed *a lot* since this answer was posted, and a lot of the comparison is now invalid. Care to make an update? You don't have to, like, rewrite the answer, but if you'd just comment here and mention how you see things now, it would be great.

Comment: I don't know details about OkHttp. I'm sorry I'm so busy as the founder of [Authlete, Inc.](https://www.authlete.com/) ("[API security startup Authlete raises $1.2m in seed funding](https://www.techinasia.com/authlete-gets-seed-funding-500-startups)") I can't spare time to look into OkHttp and update the list of consideration points. Regarding changes since my answer, see [CHANGES.md](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client/blob/master/CHANGES.md). Please note nv-websocket-client is just my hobby while OkHttp seems a big project having 138 contributors.

Comment: @TakahikoKawasaki Totally understandable. Thanks! And good luck with your startup!

Comment: You are a true hero!

Comment: Let me be the lucky hundredth!

Comment: In nv-websocket-client source code (ws/client/WritingThread.java), I saw `synchronized(this)` is used everywhere, I really concern about the performance - I'm trying to use LMAX Disruptor to achieve lock-free in the main path (consists of a set of data processing pipelines) of my own program. I'm thinking a ConcurrentLinkedQueue or BlockedLinkedQueue interface from the client may fit my writing the best.

Answer (score 4):

Some other considerations:

Tyrus works on Android. However, the SSL libraries it uses in Android 5.0 are buggy and [fail SSL handshakes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28011581/4107809).  This is supposed to be fixed in newer versions of Android, but with the way that Android is not updated on many devices, this may be a problem for you.

Depending on how SSL is implemented for other websocket implementations, this may also be a problem.

AndroidAsync does not have this SSL issue. It does have other issues like [not being able to set timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29548199/4107809).

Answer (score 1):

a) Add this file in gradle file

`compile 'com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0'`

b) Add these lines in Application Activity:

```
    public class MyApplication extends Application {
     private Socket mSocket;
        {
            try {
               mSocket = IO.socket(Config.getBaseURL());

            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        public Socket getSocket() {
            return mSocket;
        }
}
```

c) Add this function to your activity, where you called WebSocket:

```
     private void websocketConnection() {
            //Get websocket from application
            MyApplication app = (MyApplication ) getApplication();
            mSocket = app.getSocket();
            mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT, onConnect);
            mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_DISCONNECT, onDisconnect);
            mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, onConnectError);
            mSocket.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, onConnectError);
            mSocket.on("messageFromServer", onNewLocation);
            mSocket.connect();
        } 


    private Emitter.Listener onConnect = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                if (!isConnected) {

                    RequestSocket mRequestSocket = new RequestSocket();

                    mRequestSocket.setToken("anil_singhania");
                   /* your parameter */
                    mSocket.emit("messageFromClient", new Gson().toJson(mRequestSocket));
                    Log.i("Socket Data", new Gson().toJson(mRequestSocket));
                    isConnected = true;
                }
            });
        }
    };

    private Emitter.Listener onDisconnect = args -> runOnUiThread(() -> {
        isConnected = false;
       /* Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                R.string.disconnect, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
    });

    private Emitter.Listener onConnectError = args -> runOnUiThread(() -> {
         /*   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            R.string.error_connect, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()*/
    });

    private Emitter.Listener onNewLocation = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(() -> {


            });
        }
    };
```

Comment: This not support ws:// protocol.