# How can i connect to a WebSocket from a Java console program?

Tags: java, websocket, java-websocket

I am new in Java.  I've created a simple WebSocket.

```
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
import java.io.IOException;


@ServerEndpoint("/RankixSocket")
public class RankixSocket {

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Connected");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, String message) {
        System.out.println("New message : " + message);
        try {
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Message received -> :" + message);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose() {
        System.out.println("Closed");
    }

}
```

Now i want to connect to the WebSocket from the console application. I've seen an [example](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-2/) of connecting to the `WebSocket` from `Android Application`. In that example the author used an [external library](https://github.com/koush/android-websockets). I've googled a lot but nothing found helpful :( .

1. Is it possible to connect to a `WebSocket` from a normal Java console application ? then How can i do that? Is there any external libraries ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EchoClient.java` is a simple console application which connects to `ws://echo.websocket.org`. The application uses **[nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client)** library. What you should consider when selecting a WebSocket client library for Java are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30561545/1174054).

Comment: Wow, but how can i get the `JAR` version of that library @Takahiko Kawasaki

Comment: If you are using Maven or Gradle, read [README.md](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client/blob/master/README.md). Otherwise, download a JAR file from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/neovisionaries/nv-websocket-client/).

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question #1... **YES**!

Client library: [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/)

Example: [Stack Overflow Example 26452903](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452903/javax-websocket-client-simple-example)

However, I would suggest maybe rethink the communication protocol you may be using. You could utilize some other protocol that provides the most benefit based on the solution you are employing. Just food for thought.