# Android c# Websocket tutorial

Tags: c#, android, websocket

Hi I'm trying to learn how to write websockets in Android. The Android app must connect to a .Net application written in C#.

I've found a couple of tutorials outlining what websockets are:

[link 1](http://jwebsocket.org/about-jws/Press-Articles/android/introduction-websockets-android)

[link 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications)

[link 3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server)

Has anybody got a link to an Android/C# example that I could follow?

Thanks in advance

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to concern C# in Android even the server is written in C# as the *websocket protocol* can be implemented in any programming language.

Besides of your learning materials, if your server should be written in C# and Android have to connect to it, shortest path to achieve is to use **SignalR** project.

check out [SignalR Project link (http://signalr.net/)](http://signalr.net/)

SignalR use WebSocket as main protocol and http long-polling technology as a fallback. And, [Android library named SignalA is supported also](https://github.com/erizet/SignalA). I tested it and was happy to use it last year. The fallback(long-polling) is important as Android does not support WebSocket protocol in all versions.

If long-polling is not your option (it can consume cellular data plan more than expected), then you can try to create your own communication rule with raw WebSocket protocol, For that, use [Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) project in Android and many C# libraries are introduced in [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/733297/WebSocket-libraries-comparison).

Comment: hey thanks just what i'm looking for. Are there anythings to watch out for in the setup?

Answer (score 0):

See "[Which WebSocket library to use in Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30547517/1174054)" when you select a WebSocket client library for Android.

[Java-WebSocket](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) *"has a quite a few [open issues](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/issues), especially about SSL connections"*.