# Sending Data Directly To Android Phone from Raspberry Pi

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

In my application that is under development  I  have to send data directly from raspberry pi 2 to an android device .

I have successfully implemented the following Solutions

**Solution 1 :** 
Using Google Messaging Service

**Using Cloud Based Server :** 
By Sending data through API to a cloud based server which will send the data using pushy but that is also similar process as above.

All of the above solutions work but they are too slow is there any way i can directly interact with the android device from rapsberry pi ?

Comment: Have a server directly in your network. Or let the raspberry be the server. Let the information be on a database on the raspberry. The Android phone could do some polling to check if there is new data for it. If it is, it can directly read the data from the database. Consider, that both devices have to be in the same network (wifi for example). Otherwise it should take as long as using the cloud based server, I guess. I think the key here is, that the client (Android) should get its data by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a websocket connection. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547517/which-websocket-library-to-use-in-android-app)  for a list of library you can use.