# ssl == null, java NullPointerException

Tags: android, websocket

I'm implementing Secure WebSocket in Android (client side) using [Too TallNate WebSocket library](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket)

but encountering error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: ssl == null.
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try to find another WebSocket client library that supports SSL in a better matter. TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket has many open issues regarding SSL support.

Comment: did you solve??

Comment: @TakahikoKawasaki can you suggest any other library. I am also facing same issue "org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0"

Comment: @SuhasBachewar Read [Which WebSocket library to use in Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30547517/1174054) and choose one you like.