# Using nv-websocket-client on Android

Tags: java, android, websocket

I am testing nv-websocket-client on Android using Android Studio 2.2.3/JRE1.8.0_76.

My code is basically the same as the echo sample application in the README.md file.  The class runs fine under Java 8 Update 111, but fails under Android Studio.  I walked the code in debug mode and it failed at:

Source:com/neovisionaries/ws/client/Address.java:36

```
InetSocketAddress toInetSocketAddress()
{
    return new InetSocketAddress(mHost, mPort);// mHost = "echo.websocket.org", mPort = 80.
}
```

Error message in Android Studio:

```
Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate java.net.InetSocketAddress.toString()
```

Any idea what I did wrong here?

My Test Class:

```
public class TestWS {

private String m_msg;
private String m_uriStr; // = "ws://echo.websocket.org";
private static final int TIMEOUT = 5000;

public TestWS(String uriStr) {
    m_uriStr = uriStr;
    m_msg = "";
}

public void RunTest() {
    try {
        // Connect to the echo server.
        WebSocket ws = connect();
        ws.sendText("This is a test");
        Thread.sleep(1000); // Make sure m_msg is updated before function return.
        ws.disconnect();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        m_msg += "Exception: " + ex.getMessage(); // getMessage() returns null.
    }
}

private WebSocket connect() throws IOException, WebSocketException
{
    return new WebSocketFactory()
            .setConnectionTimeout(TIMEOUT)
            .createSocket(m_uriStr)
            .addListener(new WebSocketAdapter() {
                // A text message arrived from the server.
                @Override
                public void onTextMessage(WebSocket websocket, String message) {
                    m_msg += "Echo: " + message;
                }
            })
            .addExtension(WebSocketExtension.PERMESSAGE_DEFLATE)
            .connect(); // <= failed in this function.
}

public String GetMsg(){
    return m_msg;
}
}
```

Comment: I found in a comment for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547517/which-websocket-library-to-use-in-android-app that this library requires JDK8 and thus won't run on Android.  Anybody knows if this is true?

Comment: did you found the solution for this? in my case I'm trying to re-connect with different address, and I got error, but message is NULL, so, no clue what happens..

Comment: No I didn't find any solution and had to switch to another web-socket client.